# How to set maxage and maxversions for bigtable table at the same time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

Could someone please let me know how could I set the `maxage` and `maxversions` policy for bigtable table at the same time in Google Cloud Platform. I tried to use below commands but only one policy is getting reflected for the table. I need both  policies to be set.

Commands I used:

```
cbt -project <project_name> -instance <instance_name> setgcpolicy <table_name> <column_family> maxage=30d maxversions=100
cbt -project <project_name> -instance <instance_name> setgcpolicy <table_name> <column_family> "maxage=30d" && "maxversions=100"
cbt -project <project_name> -instance <instance_name> setgcpolicy <table_name> <column_family> maxage=30d and maxversions=100
cbt -project <project_name> -instance <instance_name> setgcpolicy <table_name> <column_family> maxage=30d|maxversions=100
```

The next `setgcpolicy` policy I set is just over-riding the previous policy.

The expected output should be as below -

```
cbt -project <project_name> -instance <instance_name> ls <table_name>
Family Name     GC Policy
-----------     ---------
rec             (age() > 30d || versions() > 100)
```

Could you please direct me on how to achieve the above output
FYI, for all the tries/commands I am only seeing below output which shows only one policy set.

```
Family Name     GC Policy
-----------     ---------
demoSeg         versions() > 1
<columne_family>          age() > 30d
```

Could you please direct me on this requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to update your cbt tool. The feature for setting multiple garbage collection was added in the past few months, so it's likely you haven't updated since then.

Run this to update your tool:

```
gcloud components update
```

I'm on version "cbt 0.9.0 6ab8d8ff 2020-02-07 17:57:00", and I was able to successfully do this using the commands you specified:

```
bigtable[master]$ cbt createtable gc-test
bigtable[master]$ cbt createfamily gc-test cf
bigtable[master]$ cbt setgcpolicy gc-test cf maxage=30d and maxversions=100
bigtable[master]$ cbt ls gc-test
Family Name GC Policy
----------- ---------
cf      (age() > 30d && versions() > 100)
```

Also, when using || and && for your policy definition instead of "and"/"or", you should put the entire policy in quotes ([more info here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference#set_the_garbage-collection_policy_age_versions_for_a_column_family)):

```
cbt -project <project_name> -instance <instance_name> setgcpolicy <table_name> <column_family> "maxage=30d && maxversions=100"
```